# Why is this code showing number 2 multiple times?

Tags: python

So I'm trying to make a calculator but when i do plus (also with other things but for example) it does work but after the outcome comes it asks for number 2 again, I just want the code to start again.

this is the plus piece of the code:

```
 q = input(str("Wil je de bewerkingsteken legende zien? (j/n): "))

        if q == "J" or q == "j" :
            print ("\nplus = + ")
            print ("min = -")
            print ("maal = X")
            print ("delen door = :")
            print ("quadrateren = Q")
            print ("tot de kracht van = P")
            print ("Worteltrekken = W")
            print ("Procent = %")
            
            num1 = float(input("\n Nummer 1: "))
            bew = input("\n Bewerkingsteken: ")
            num1_word = (str(num1))

        

            if bew == "+" :
                plus_num2 = input(float("\nNummer 2: "))
                plus_num2_con = (str(plus_num2))
                plus_out = (num1 + plus_num2)
                plus_out1 = (str(plus_out)) 
                print ("\n" + num1_con +" + " + num2_con + " = " + plus_out1)
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you write the input wrong for plus_num2. Try this;

```
plus_num2 = float(input("\nNummer 2: "))
```

Second, you define the number's name different from last print function. Try This;

```
print ("\n" + num1_word +" + " + plus_num2_con + " = " + plus_out1)
```

Third, if you want to start the code again you can add `while True` on first line.

Comment: I tried it and all the things you said were correct, but it still doesnt work, it have no idea why, it just prints (translated): 'number 1, \n operator:, \n number 2, \n (then the outcome) '##and THEN 'number 2:' AGAIN while i don't want number 2 again because the sum as already complete

Comment: Solved it! was just a dumb little thing